# Performance warning on React native list

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have a project in react native with expo and TS, I have a screen in which I render several elements (or at least it is expected that as time increases it will grow more), I am having the following log.

```
VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update 
- make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. 
{"contentLength": 5264, "dt": 835, "prevDt": 983}
```

It always gives me that log when I get to the end of the list, and I only render 10 elements (each element has an image or video and text, 10 elements is little compared to what is expected later), I will put the flatlist code
​

```
return (
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            className='bg-neutral-900'
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            ListHeaderComponent={() => (
                //Views ....
            )}
            ListFooterComponent={() => (
                //... more code
            )}
            renderItem={RendeItem} // useCallback
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            onEndReached={async () => await reFetch()}
            // performance
            removeClippedSubviews={true}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
            initialNumToRender={3}
        />
    );
```

The function that requests the data again updates the state to add at the end what is new and at the end I get the error, how can I solve it? or any way to have better performance?

I suspect that maybe it's because I want to make the list dynamic and performance is affected by that, anyway, I want to solve that problem and thinking about making it a longer list in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are many articles online that provides some tips for your problem. Generally speaking this warning comes when RN cannot keep up on making new items in the list. Unfortunately, lists are pretty heavy components if not optimized.

[Official Guide - React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration)

[Medium - Optimizing FlatList Performance in React Native](https://medium.com/@ajkhatibi/optimizing-flatlist-performance-in-react-native-a83b1315ded9)

Or you can use alternatives for the FlatList, such as [FlashList](https://github.com/Shopify/flash-list) (a drop-in solution) and see if it's better.

The way you can surely start is analyzing your render item and make all the possibile optimizations to make it less computational-expensive. Then make sure your FlatList is optimized as well. Then, if nothing works, try other solutions.